# How to repair a mp4 file?

Tags: mp4, repair

The end of the file is damaged because battery of digicam became empty.

I tried to repair it with

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

It crashed.
How can I copy a destroyed file without checking it and copy it without the last 2 minutes to another file.

Comment: Which operating system? Converting with VLC usually works

Comment: Sorry,  no,
I ll try to open input.mp4
crash
I did try convert
crash
I tried to stream
crash
I ll try avidemux
crash.

Thank You.
Regards

Comment: We do use Linux.

Comment: "It crashed" -- How? Kernel panic? Segmentation fault? Or did `ffmpeg` itself work but gave you an error due to problematic input data? What was the error? Please [edit] and add this information to the question.

Comment: IMO you best use untrunc for these type of issues, https://github.com/anthwlock/untrunc

Answer (score 1):

Here are several ways available to repair corrupted MP4 files:

1. Transcoding Using VLC
2. Repair Corrupt File Index and File Header using VLC
3. Increase the Cache Value in the VLC Player
4. Replicate the Video File to Gain Access in VLC
5. Repair MP4 with Video Repair Tool or Online Video Repair Tool, such as UltraRepair...

More details, pls refer to this article:[Workable Methods to Repair Corrupted MP4 Video Files](https://www.imyfone.com/repair-file/repair-mp4-video-files/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).