How to reassemble raw packet data back into a new MP4 file with FFmpeg?
I am using FFmpeg.
I use the following command to get all packet info:
ffprobe -print_format json -show_packets -show_streams -show_entries packet=pts,duration,size,codec_type,pos test.mp4 > test.mp4.info

Then based on each packet info, such as the one below:
{
    "codec_type": "video",
    "pts": 0,
    "duration": 512,
    "size": "6419",
    "pos": "175"
}

I extract the raw data of the packet from the test.mp4 file, take the above packet as a example, I extract the data at offset = 175 and size = 6419, then save the packet into a new file, video_sample0.dat.
I write an app to write all the packets into different audio and video files, i.e., audio_sample0.dat,
audio_sample1.dat, …, video_sample0.dat, video_sample1.dat, …
Then I use FFprobe with -show_data option to show the raw data of each packet, then compare the output with my packet files and confirm they are identical.
After that, I remove some packets. Then try to recreate a new MP4 file with the remaining packets.
I take one packet file as a test:
ffmpeg -f m4v -i video_sample0.dat -c copy output.mp4

But get the following error:
ffmpeg version 7.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 14.1.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-shared
  libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
[mpeg4 @ 00628400] time_increment_bits 0 is invalid in relation to the current bitstream, this is likely caused by a missing VOL header
[mpeg4 @ 00628400] time_increment_bits set to 5 bits, based on bitstream analysis
[mpeg4 @ 00628400] time_increment_bits 4 is invalid in relation to the current bitstream, this is likely caused by a missing VOL header
[mpeg4 @ 00628400] time_increment_bits set to 5 bits, based on bitstream analysis
[mpeg4 @ 00628400] looks like this file was encoded with (divx4/(old)xvid/opendivx) -> forcing low_delay flag
[m4v @ 003e8d00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mpeg4, yuv420p): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, m4v, from 'video_sample0.dat':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 25 fps, 1200k tbr, 1200k tbn
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
[mp4 @ 00628400] dimensions not set
[out#0/mp4 @ 0062b380] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Conversion failed!

So, how to reassemble the raw packet data back to a new MP4 file?
Update
The extracted video is in MPEG4 format, which is obtained from ffprobe:
"streams": [
    {
        "index": 0,
        "codec_name": "mpeg4",
        "codec_long_name": "MPEG-4 part 2",
        "profile": "Simple Profile",
        "codec_type": "video",
        "codec_tag_string": "mp4v",
        "codec_tag": "0x7634706d",
        "width": 352,
        "height": 288,
        "coded_width": 352,
        "coded_height": 288,
        "closed_captions": 0,
        "film_grain": 0,
        "has_b_frames": 0,
        "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
        "display_aspect_ratio": "11:9",
        "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
        "level": 1,
        "chroma_location": "left",
        "refs": 1,
        "quarter_sample": "false",
        "divx_packed": "false",
        "id": "0x1",
        "r_frame_rate": "25/1",
        "avg_frame_rate": "251/10",
        "time_base": "1/12800",
        "start_pts": 0,
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration_ts": 128000,
        "duration": "10.000000",
        "bit_rate": "544953",
        "nb_frames": "251",
        "nb_read_packets": "251",
        "extradata_size": 46,
        "disposition": {
            "default": 1,
            "dub": 0,
            "original": 0,
            "comment": 0,
            "lyrics": 0,
            "karaoke": 0,
            "forced": 0,
            "hearing_impaired": 0,
            "visual_impaired": 0,
            "clean_effects": 0,
            "attached_pic": 0,
            "timed_thumbnails": 0,
            "non_diegetic": 0,
            "captions": 0,
            "descriptions": 0,
            "metadata": 0,
            "dependent": 0,
            "still_image": 0
        },
        "tags": {
            "language": "und",
            "handler_name": "VideoHandler",
            "vendor_id": "[0][0][0][0]"
        }
    },

I original use the following command to add the packet:
ffmpeg -f mpeg4 -i video_sample0.dat -c copy output.mp4

But get the following error:
Unknown input format: 'mpeg4'

I ask AI and it suggests me to use m4v instead.

First of all, was the video stream even really m4v? (Note that m4v does NOT mean "any kind of video stream muxed in a '.mp4'".) Or was it really h264 (AVC) or hevc (H.265)? Besides, why did you even extract the raw data that way (while ffmpeg has raw video "muxer" for all three types of codec)? (I have no idea if any crucial information in the "raw video stream" would be lost when you do that.)

If you manually extract the packets, you almost certainly miss out on the codec extradata. But first, why?

@TomYan, I have updated with the ffprobe stream info which should it is mpeg4 format. I do with the raw packet data because I need to manually remove some packets.

@Gyan, In the real case, I have many MP4 file that are truncated in their tails, which make them not playable. I check these files and find all boxes are OK, except for mdat, which makes some packets lost(<= 5%). All the metadata for the stream and packets are OK. So I write a Test app and try to assemble the remaining packets and the metadata back to a new MP4 file.

VLC already has MP4 repair functions built in to it, as do other utilities. I think this question may be an effective duplicate, rather than trying to reinvent a wheel: https://superuser.com/questions/1728218/how-to-repair-a-mp4-file

This question is similar to: How to repair a mp4 file?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JoepvanSteen I had a bunch of files that were truncated at the end too. I just told ffmpeg to copy (no recoding) all streams from one truncated file into to a new one. It did output a few warnings/errors, but it completed the stream copy, and that made the video playable. All the way up where the video data ended.

can you use .mkvcontainer, which is very tolerant to any kind of timing or codec issues ?

Lets say your video has 3 frames, each 100 bytes and 512 milliseconds long:
[
{
    "codec_type": "video",
    "pts": 0,
    "duration": 512,
    "size": "100",
    "pos": "0"
},
{
    "codec_type": "video",
    "pts": 0,
    "duration": 512,
    "size": "100",
    "pos": "100"
},
{
    "codec_type": "video",
    "pts": 0,
    "duration": 512,
    "size": "100",
    "pos": "200"
}
]

Lets say you want to remove frame #2,
let's make the concat text file, omitting frame #2:
file 'subfile,,start,0,end,99,,:video_sample0.dat'
duration 0.512
file 'subfile,,start,200,end,299,,:video_sample0.dat'
duration 0.512

notice that frame #2 which would have been
file 'subfile,,start,100,end,199,,:video_sample0.dat'
duration 0.512

is omitted.
now give it to ffmpeg:

ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist concat,ffconcat,file,subfile,data -i ConcatTextFile.txt -fps_mode vfr output.mp4

should work..
Btw i'm doing something similar in this library (which I wrote myself)
Maybe the code in the library can help you.

Thank you for your solution. I try it with a special case, one frame in the contact file, as below "file 'subfile,,start,0,end,7748,,:video_sample0.dat'
duration 0.18594" and ffmpeg return the following result "[luodat @ 00b59a40] Format luodat detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[concat @ 00b57000] Impossible to open 'subfile,,start,0,end,7748,,:video_sample0.dat'
[in#0 @ 00b58ec0] Error opening input: End of file
Error opening input file ConcatTextFile.txt.
Error opening input files: End of file"

Also I notice you do not specify the codec for the frame, as the frame data itself do not contain such info.

@alancc .. how big is your video_sample0.dat ? the error suggest that byte #7748 (or #7747) does not exist in video_sample0.dat

@alancc or maybe ConcatTextFile.txt does not exist.. run a strace on it, what does strace say?

I recheck video_sample0.dat and find I input its size incorrectly. I fix that and use the following contact file: file 'subfile,,start,0,end,6418,,:video_sample0.dat'
duration 0.512. But still get the error: [luodat @ 01589a40] Format luodat detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[concat @ 01587000] Impossible to open 'subfile,,start,0,end,6418,,:video_sample0.dat'
[in#0 @ 01588ec0] Error opening input: End of file
Error opening input file ConcatTextFile.txt.
Error opening input files: End of file

ConcatTextFile.txt should exists, otherwise, ffmpeg will not output the error: Impossible to open 'subfile,,start,0,end,6418,,:video_sample0.dat' since this is the line in ConcatTextFile.txt. I am under Windows, so strace is not available.

Is there any document on the format of the contact file? I only find this one: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate. But it does not cover the format you used.

@alancc subfile documentation is available here https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html  but the documentation is not very good.. but how big is your video_sample0.dat ? is at least 6419 bytes big?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
